# Is it possible to provide a service in a component with a parameter?

Tags: angular

I have this service `CredentialService` that has two functions to tell which observable I want to subscribe

```
class CredentialService{
    private observableState$$: Subject;
    public observableState$ = this.observableState$$.asObservable()
    listenToLoginObs(): {}

    listenToReauthObs(): {}

    constructor(some: Other, dependencies:Here){}
   // ....
}
```

This service is provided and instantiated in each component that needs it. Right now in each `NgOnInit` I call `listenToLoginObs` or `listenToReauthObs` as needed.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'login-componente',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./logincomponent.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  providers: [CredentialService]
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit(){

 constructor(private credentialService: CredentialService){}
  public ngOnInit(): void {
     this.credentialService.listenToLoginObs()
  }
}
```

I wonder if there is a way to configure this directly in the providers array so I do not need to manually call `listenToLoginObs` or `listenToReauthObs` on `ngOnInit` (with out a big overhead). ?